# How to show existence of a set related to primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How could one show the result that

Let $a , b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Then the set $\{a+bc: c \in \mathbb{N}\}$ contains an infinite subset

$Q=\{q_{1},q_{2},...\}$ such that $\gcd(q_{j},q_{k})=1$ unless $j=k$

Without invoking L functions or Dirichlet theorem on arithmetic progression?

Could it be done in a more simple way since it is less strict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll use an argument similar to Euclid's [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_theorem#Euclid.27s_proof) that there are infinitely many primes (in fact, they are the same argument if we take $a = b = 1$).

Since $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, $a$ and $b$ are positive. Let's define $q_1 = a+b$ and for $n \geq 1$,

$$q_{n+1} = a + b q_1 q_2 \cdots q_n$$

so the $q_n$'s are strictly increasing, hence distinct, and are contained in $\{a + bc : c \in \mathbb{N}\}$. First note that by induction we have $\gcd(a, q_n) = 1$ for each $n$, since 
$$\gcd(a, q_1) = \gcd(a, a+b) = \gcd(a, b) = 1,$$

and for $n \geq 1$, assuming $\gcd(a, q_i) = 1$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$, we have

$$\gcd(a, q_{n+1}) = \gcd(a, a + b q_1 q_2 \cdots q_n) = \gcd(a, b q_1 q_2 \cdots q_n) = 1.$$

Now for $j \neq k$, we can assume $j > k$, which gives

$$\gcd(q_j, q_k) = \gcd(a + bq_1 q_2 \cdots q_k \cdots q_{j-1}, q_k) = \gcd(a, q_k) = 1$$

so $Q = \{q_1, q_2, \dots\}$ is such an infinite subset.